# Creating NationalInstruments.Common.Native.dll in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012, .net-4.5

I've written a stored procedure to be deployed to a SQL Server 2012 database. The stored procedure as written references a number of assemblies, including `NationalInstruments.Common.Native.dll`.

When I try to publish the stored procedure, I get the following error:

> *SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 6503, Level 16, State 12, Line 1 Assembly 'nationalinstruments.visans, version=9.0.40.156, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=dc6ad606294fc298.' was not found in the SQL catalog.*

I tried adding the assembly to the database using `CREATE ASSEMBLY with PERMISSION_SET=UNSAFE` and `TRUSTWORTHY ON`. This has worked for me before, when adding `System.Messaging` to the database. When doing the same for `NationalInstruments.Common.Native.dll`, I get the following error:

> *Msg 6544, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>
>   CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'NationalInstruments.Common.Native' failed because assembly 'NationalInstruments.Common.Native' is malformed or not a pure .NET assembly. 
>   Unverifiable PE Header/native stub.*

I understand that SQLCLR does not support assemblies written in native (unmanaged code). However, I really need `NationalInstruments.Common.Native.dll`, as it is referenced by `NationalInstruments.Common.dll`, which is in turn referenced by `NationalInstruments.VisaNS`, which is essential to the functionality of my stored procedure.

Is there any way to get around using `NationalInstruments.Common.Native.dll`, or to somehow convert it to a pure .NET assembly of managed code?

(I don't know if this is relevant, but the stored procedure is written in C# targeted to the .NET Framework 4.5,  using Visual Studio 2012.)

Comment: I don't have an answer, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325386/how-to-combine-chilkat-library-into-sql-server-clr) and the [discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlnetfx/thread/4a032c4b-1402-4c53-b34e-8c8bd724f904) it links to suggest that there may be ways to load unmanaged code into SQL Server but that it's definitely not a good idea. Unfortunately since you have no control over the DLL, your options are limited.

Comment: How might I go about writing a wrapper for the DLL?